# Fitting power law for income distribution

Tags: r, power-law

I am working with micro-data on total net household income for different countries and before computing inequality indexes, I want to adjust the right tail to take into account the sensitivity of these indexes to top incomes and top-missing. Therefore, I am trying to fit a power law distribution for the right tail with the poweRlaw package. 
However, I get some weird estimates for Xmin. I used the following code:

```
m_c1<-conpl$new(country2_1$hi100_eur)
est=estimate_xmin(m_c1)
m_c1$setXmin(est)
```

The resulting Xmin is: 99863, but for the country in question this means roughly the 25th percentile. 
(the mean income in this case is 223290, danish coronas). 
Indeed, plotting the qqnorm it is possible to observe that the deviations of the right tail starts much above than the estimated Xmin, but around the 95th percentile (the red line):

[image]

Finally, also plotting the cdf of the estimated power law with the minimum obtained, it is clearly not an optimal fit:

[image]

Given the large dataset, I report the column-vector (household income) I am using to fit the Power law:

```
dput(head(country2_1$hi100_eur))
country2_1$hi100_eur<-c(97000, 126550, 90000, 249500, 249500, 156166)
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: "Any idea on what I am doing wrong?" No, we don't even know what you are doing because we don't have a reproducible example (including data and information regarding which package your are using).

Comment: I'm using Power Law package (as reported). I have updated the question with `dput(head(country2_1$hi100_eur))`. It's a large data frame, but this vector is what I'm using for fitting the power law

Comment: In order to answer your question we need to be able to completely reproduce your dataset.  This looks odd, so raise an issue at https://github.com/csgillespie/poweRlaw But I need to be able to access data that reproduces this issue.

Comment: @csgillespie shall I copy the result of the dput for the all 5899 household income observations?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Prof. Gillespie for the clarification I realized the problem was in the definition of xmax. By default it is set at 1e5, but my data are larger than xmax=1e5. 
Modifying the xmax range (or setting the xmin) the fitting of the Power Law works without any weird results.